# How to implement something like Try to get a value, if null then sleep a little without using Thread.sleep?

Tags: java

At one point in my application, I need to ask a cache (a HashMap, i.e.) for a value. If the value does not exist, I need to wait a little and try again. At the moment, this is implemented like this:

```
String result = cache.get(key);

for (int i = 0; result == null; i++) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }

    result = cache.get(key);
}
```

While it works, I have a feeling that using `Thread.sleep` is kinda false. Does the JDK provide anything for this sort of task? I thought about using an `ScheduledExecutorService`, but the thing is that it has to run in the main thread.

Comment: How about java.util.Timer and TimerTask?

Comment: Then execution won't be on main thread :(

Comment: Would it be possible to have the cache notify this code when the element was added? Then you could use either wait(), and nofity() on some object acting as a lock, or you could use a [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) with a condition if Java 5+

Comment: If you feel that Thread.sleep is not right because you have to handle that InterruptedException... then you can use [LockSupport.parkNanos()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) from the [Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). The native implementation is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that your design is fundamentally problematic. Locking and memory visibility issues notwithstanding, you are essentially polling for an event using high level code. This is neither efficient nor very responsive w.r.t. latency.

You should switch to a more event-driven approach. At the very least, use an [object monitor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) or a [lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) to wait for that value to be set, rather than polling.

Even better, use a message bus to register handlers and process events as they come - you can easily construct a multithreaded message bus using any [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) implementation to pass message objects.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the BlockingQueue as a cache.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anyway around Thread.sleep if you really have to execute on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Other possibility is using `Object.wait()`. It is almost like `Thread.sleep()` for you but supports interrupting by calling `notify()` on the same monitor.

Other possibility for you is to user `java.util.Timer`= (as was already mentioned by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [self populating cache](http://codingjunkie.net/google-guava-cache/)(guava [LoadingCache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html)), so the get(...) will block until the data is fetched.

Combine it with a [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) -> `Future#get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` And you could have timeouts too.

Hope i pointed you into the right direction :)